# Android Studio: Set mp3 from raw folder as device ringtone in 2020

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ringtone

I'd like to set a raw mp3 file, which is located in my raw folder, as the device ringtone (using java). Unfortunately the old tutorials do not work anymore, often because you need some write permissions. I tried everything out there, but no solution works (the solutions are all veery old...).

Can anyone help me please? Has anyone a good code example for that problem?

Comment: here is the official documentation
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind putting your file in assets folder then you can do this :

- copy your mp3 from assets to device accessible memory
- set the new copied file as ringtone using

  ```
                      void set_asset_ringtone(Context context, String output_file_path, String asset_name) throws IOException {

                       ///////////////copying from assets to filepath////////////////
                   InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(asset_name);
                   String outFileName =output_file_path+"/"+asset_name;

                   OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                   int bytesRead;
                   while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                       localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                   }
                   localDbStream.close();
                   externalDbStream.close();
                   //////Setting the ringtone /////////////////
                   File rigntone_file=new File(outFileName);
                   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, rigntone_file.getAbsolutePath());
                   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "ring");
                   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
                   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, rigntone_file.length());
                   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
                   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
                   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
                   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

                   Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(rigntone_file.getAbsolutePath());
                   Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);


                   try {
                       RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
                   } catch (Throwable t) {

                   }

               }
  ```

You will need these permisions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And maybe

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Thank you! What did you use as output_file_path? I used: String exStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                path=(exStoragePath +"/media/alarms/");  But then later I get an FileNotFoundException in this line: OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);